# How get across the library in the French chateau?

Tags: uncharted-3

I'm playing *Uncharted 3* and I'm stuck in the library of the French chateau. I need to help Sully move some beam, but I can't see how to get across.

I tried jumping on either side of the room or tried climbing, but it doesn't seem to work.  Drake said something about lifting the chandelier, but I don't see anything I can interact with.

**So how do I get to the other side of the library?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You climb to the side opposite of Sully.  Once there jump to the hanging chandelier and use it to jump to the opposite side of the room.  On that wall there is a crank that you can operate using the triangle button that will raise the chandelier and allow you to use it to jump across again.

Comment: Didn't notice there was a gap in the middle I could jump through, thanks for the tip!